# Como criar um array infinito?

Tags: java, array

estou com um probleminha e preciso, de alguma forma, criar um array infinito, ou melhor, indefinido, o usuário poder entrar quantos dados forem necessários...

Como eu poderia fazê-lo? Estou usando o JDK6.

Comment: Infinito é bem diferente de indefinido. Se for infinito a tua aplicação "estoira"

Comment: Um `ArrayList` não serve pra você não? E os dados estão em que formato? (tipo primitivo ou objeto)

Comment: Tipo primitivo.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Em Java os arrays têm tamanho fixo, especificados na criação. Se você precisa armazenar mais elementos que cabem no array, sua única saída é criar um novo array, maior, e copiar os elementos já existentes pra ele (mais o novo que você está querendo adicionar).

Felizmente, tem uma classe pronta que faz isso pra você: [`java.util.ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). Você usa ela como uma lista, normalmente, e a biblioteca cuida dos detalhes internos pra você:

```
ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();
lista.add("foo");
lista.add("bar");
lista.add("baz"); // Quantos elementos quiser, desde que caiba na memória
for ( String s : lista )
    System.out.println(s);
```

Se passar um parâmetro inteiro pro construtor, você especifica a "capacidade inicial" da lista (i.e. o tamanho inicial do array interno - de modo que você possa armazenar X elementos antes da lista se redimensionar pela primeira vez). Isso pode melhorar a performance, caso você tenha uma ideia de quantos elementos o sistema usualmente terá que suportar (no caso médio - não tem problema se no pior caso ele precisar de mais).

Para uma alternativa baseada em listas encadeadas em vez de arrays (com as vantagens e desvantagens correspondentes), veja [`java.util.LinkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html).

### Nota quanto aos tipos de dados

Se seus dados forem objetos complexos (incluindo strings), essa é a solução mais direta. No caso de tipos primitivos, por outro lado, o uso de listas traria o *overhead* do **autoboxing**:

```
ArrayList<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<Integer>();
lista.add(10);        // autobox
int x = lista.get(0); // autounbox
```

Nesse caso, cada elemento na lista vai ocupar memória adicional (uns `24 bytes` por elemento numa plataforma 32 bits, se não me engano). Se isso for problema pra você, só resta usar arrays simples mesmo, e fazer o redimensionamento manualmente.

```
class ListaInts {
    private int[] lista = new int[8];
    private int length = 0;

    public void add(int i) {
        if ( length == lista.length ) {
            // Copia toda a lista para um novo array, maior
            int[] novaLista = new int[lista.length * 2];
            System.arraycopy(lista, 0, novaLista, 0, length);
            // Substitui a lista original
            lista = novaLista;
        }
        lista[length++] = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: A solução de criar um novo array maior caiu como uma luva, fiz apenas uma alteração, ao invés de usar o arraycopy, usei um while.

Comment: Só mais uma coisa... O que acontece ali no `lista = novaLista;`? Ele atribui os valores, inclusive o seu tamanho para `lista`?

Comment: @Patrick A variável `lista` é uma **referência** para um array de inteiros. Inicialmente, ela apontava para um array, e posteriormente ela passa a apontar para um novo array. Não há cópia, **ambas** `lista` e `novaLista` referem-se ao mesmo array. Quanto ao array antigo, como não há mais ninguém apontando pra ele, o coletor de lixo fica livre para destruí-lo e liberar a sua região de memória para que seja usada para outros fins.

Answer (score 5):

Os vetores sempre têm que ter um tamanho definido, você não pode criá-los com um tamanho indeterminado.

Para resolver seu problema, você pode fazer isso não mão, criando novos vetores cada vez que ele atingir seu tamanho limite, ou pode usar uma a classe que o Java já criou para nos ajudar justamente com essa tarefa: `java.lang.ArrayList`, como já dito pelo @mgibsonbr.

Apenas para acrescentar à resposta dele, vou mostrar **trecho do código fonte** da classe `ArrayList` que explica como isso funciona (mas que ninguém precisa saber para poder usar):

**ArrayList.java**

```
//o atributo elementData é do tipo Object, ou seja, guarda qualquer tipo de 
//variável com que não seja um primitivo
private transient Object[] elementData;

//você pode inicializar seu ArrayList indicando o tamanho do seu vetor, mas isso 
//costuma ser irrelevante para nós
public ArrayList(int initialCapacity) {
    super();
    if (initialCapacity < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal Capacity: "+ initialCapacity);
    this.elementData = new Object[initialCapacity];
}

public ArrayList() {
    this(10); //por padrão, o ArrayList é criado com um vetor de tamanho de 10 elementos 
}

//esta é a parte que a lista aumenta seu tamanho, criando um novo vetor
//que garante que é possível armazenar todos os elementos da coleção
private void grow(int minCapacity) {
    // overflow-conscious code
    int oldCapacity = elementData.length;
    int newCapacity = oldCapacity + (oldCapacity >> 1);
    if (newCapacity - minCapacity < 0)
        newCapacity = minCapacity;
    if (newCapacity - MAX_ARRAY_SIZE > 0)
        newCapacity = hugeCapacity(minCapacity);
    // minCapacity is usually close to size, so this is a win:
    elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, newCapacity);
}
```

A classe `ArrayList` é relativamente grande, possui mais de 1000 linhas, não vou postar todas aqui, mas se tiver interesse em vê-la, ela está disponível para qualquer um ver seu código, assim como qualquer classe do JDK.

Apenas para minha resposta não ficar incompleta, aí vai um exemplo de uso:

```
List<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<Integer>();
lista.add(1); //autoboxing, transforma automaticamente de int para Integer
lista.add(5);
System.out.println("Último elemento da lista: " + lista.get(lista.size()-1));
```

Imprime:

> Último elemento da lista: 5